# Index out of bounds in an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception

I am wondering why I am getting index out of bounds even in an if statement. Should not the code not simply execute if it is false and go after the if block?. I have the following code, and its is giving me the `IndexOut of range Exception`.

```
if (rhs[0] == '+')
    {
                rhs = rhs.Replace("+", "");
    }


//Some code here
```

Comment: Your assumption is wrong. The behavior of indexing into a string is well documented. Go read it.

Comment: please include the declaration and initialization of `rhs`. This is a very important information, (also for future visitors of this post )to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably rhs is empty, and so rhs[0] does not exist. Hence an index out of bounds exception is thrown.

Try

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(rhs) && rhs[0] == '+')
...
```

Comment: Thanks, trying it

Comment: thank you- so much. It worked

Comment: Good analysis of the problem. OP posted the only question: "Should not the code not simply execute if it is false and go after the if block?" even though you have posted a working solution, you did not answer this question. It would improve your answer if you would do that